# Изображения на пропорциональном расстоянии друг от друга

Tags: html, изображения, вёрстка, css

Приветствую.
Необходимо, чтобы несколько изображений располагались на **пропорциональном расстоянии** друг от друга на устройствах с разными разрешениями - не только ширину, но и высоту. Эти изображения образуют единую "картину", поэтому пропорциональность действительно важна.
Пробую использовать **[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) (css)**,подбирая стили для разных разрешений (учитывается только width). Есть мысль использовать сервис для определения устройства по **user agent**. Все осложняется разнообразием устройств и возможностью поворота устройств (**portrait** и **landscape**)
Итак, что Вы можете посоветовать для такой проблемы?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм вы не указали сетку по которой будут расположены изображения, ответить сложно. Попробуйте указывать значения размеров в **.em** , а отношение **.em** регулировать непосредственно через [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) .

Попробуйте библиотеки : [Picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) или [HiSRC](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc) (но она не для любого проекта подойдет).

Comment: В том то и дело, что сетки нет - это единая картинка, составленная из нескольких более мелких. К библиотекам присматривался, но хотелось бы обойтись без них. В любом случае спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

если изображения по ширине одинаковые, то создайте таблицу, растяните на всю ширину, каждое изображение в свою ячейку, ячейки станут одинаковой ширины.

Comment: К сожалению, это тоже не вариант. Все изображения разного размера, расположены не по сетке и важна не только ширина, висота, но и положение относительно других элементов. Спасибо за ответ.